How can I embed an RSS feed in Linkedin?
Ich want to embed my rss feed from torial. The website of torial is torial.com/susanne.gietl.
How can I embed the feed, preferably without using an automation software or a paid software in my LinkedIn feed? Thank you very much in advance.
